# Square Root Function for the SEAL Ciphertexts

Tags: seal

Is there a way to calculate the square root function on Ciphertexts? I didn't see it see it in the evaluator method. If it's not possible with SEAL 2.3.1 will it be possible with future SEAL releases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is not in SEAL at the moment. SEAL is a low level library and aims to provide only the most fundamental building blocks; including a high-level function such as sqrt in SEAL is unreasonable since how exactly it is best evaluated (on encrypted data) depends a lot on the context. Therefore, sqrt is unlikely to ever be provided by the SEAL API.